# Почему программа неправильно считает кол-во чисел в заданном диапазоне?

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++

Произвести следующую обработку `15` вещественных чисел:

Найти среднее арифметическое положительных чисел и подсчитать кол-во чисел, входящих в диапазон `[-15,5]`

Дело в том, что программа неправильно считает кол-во чисел в заданном диапазоне `[-15,5]`. Она выводит единицу.

В чем проблема?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "Russian");
    float a[15], sum = 0; int i, kol = 0;
    printf("введите вещ. числа\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        scanf_s("%f", &a[i]);
    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        if ((a[i] >= -15.0) && (a[i] <= 5.0))
            kol++;
        if (a[i] > 0)
            sum += a[i];
    }
    printf("Сред. ариф.=%f\n", (float)sum / 15);
    printf("кол-во чисел в диапазоне [-15..5]=%d", kol);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ```положительных чисел``` вы точно это условие описали в коде? а то не нашел :(

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков переписала код, а кол-во чисел все равно неправильно выводит. Прикол в том, что без локализации все работает как надо.Почему?

Comment: Паучье чутье мне подсказывает, что локаль меняет десятичный разделитель на `,`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, это можно исправить с сохранением локализации?

Comment: Не уверен, и винды под рукой нет, чтобы проверить.

Comment: `#include <clocale> ... std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); std::setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");`?

Comment: Всегда проверяйте результат `scanf_s`. Всегда! У вас ошибки на вводе. Вы их молча игнорируете. Массив остаётся незаполненым, кроме первого числа.

Comment: https://ideone.com/7dyga6 — вроде бы верно. так что скорее всего прав @HolyBlackCat